# Why does nextgroup not match newline without trailing whitespace?

Tags: regex, syntax, syntax-highlighting, vim

Consider the following 3 sets of highlight groups and syntax matches:

```vimscript
hi  Foo     ctermfg=black   ctermbg=red     guifg=black     guibg=red
hi  Filler  ctermfg=black   ctermbg=green   guifg=black     guibg=green
hi  Bar     ctermfg=black   ctermbg=blue    guifg=black     guibg=blue
syn match   Foo     "foo"       nextgroup=Filler
syn match   Filler  "\_s*"      nextgroup=Bar       contained
syn match   Bar     "bar"                           contained

hi  Baz     ctermfg=black   ctermbg=cyan    guifg=black     guibg=cyan
hi  Qux     ctermfg=black   ctermbg=yellow  guifg=black     guibg=yellow
syn match   Baz     "baz\_s*"   nextgroup=Qux
syn match   Qux     "qux"                           contained

hi  Abc     ctermfg=black   ctermbg=magenta guifg=black     guibg=magenta
hi  Xyz     ctermfg=black   ctermbg=white   guifg=black     guibg=white
syn match   Abc     "abc"       nextgroup=Xyz       skipwhite   skipnl
syn match   Xyz     "xyz"                           contained
```

`Filler` and `Bar` only match after `Foo`; similarly, `Qux` only after `Baz`, and `Xyz` only after `Abc`. The following examples, with `:set list` for clarity, illustrate how `Filler` and `Bar` do not match after `Foo` unless `Foo` has trailing whitespace:

[image]

The `Baz` `Qux` example verifies that `\_s` matches newlines, so why doesn't this work when `Baz` is split into `Foo` and `Filler`? This quote from [`:help syn-skipnl`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:syn-skipnl) is relevant:

> When "skipnl" is present, the match with nextgroup may be found in the next
>   line.  This only happens when the current item ends at the end of the current
>   line!  When "skipnl" is not present, the nextgroup will only be found after
>   the current item in the same line.

The `Abc` `Xyz` example, using `skipwhite` `skipnl` and without `\_s` altogether, indeed matches in both cases. Does this mean `EOL` does not qualify as "after the current item in the same line"? Certainly it can't be part of the next line? This seems to contradict the fact that a normal search for `\_s` or `\n` results in `EOL` characters matching on the same line.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you ask. The results in your screenshots seem to match what you want to do (as I understand it from your code).

Comment: I don't see why `Filler` doesn't match `EOL` on line 2, which would cause `Bar` to match line 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a match ends immediately before `\n`, the `nextgroup` argument will be ignored unless `skipnl` is also specified, even if one of the groups in `nextgroup` would have matched starting with `\n`.

In the given example, since the first `Foo` match ends immediately before `\n` and `Foo` does not specify `skipnl`, Vim does not even attempt to match `Filler`. The introduction of other whitespace allows `Filler` to match after the second `Foo` match, and since `Filler` includes `\n`, `Bar` can also match without `Filler` specifying `skipnl`.

The relevant code is in `src/syntax.c`:

```
/* nextgroup ends at end of line, unless "skipnl" or "skipempty" present */
if (current_next_list != NULL
        && syn_getcurline()[current_col + 1] == NUL
        && !(current_next_flags & (HL_SKIPNL | HL_SKIPEMPTY)))
    current_next_list = NULL;
```

and

```
/* handle next_list, unless at end of line and no "skipnl" or
 * "skipempty" */
current_next_list = cur_si->si_next_list;
current_next_flags = cur_si->si_flags;
if (!(current_next_flags & (HL_SKIPNL | HL_SKIPEMPTY))
        && syn_getcurline()[current_col] == NUL)
    current_next_list = NULL;
```